# Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.auth.internal.aws4signerutils

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I encountered this exception when I try to call an endpoint from my spring boot application. What causes this exception?

`Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: could not initialize class com.amazonaws.auth.internal.aws4signerutils`

Context: my controller calls a external service class to store a file in the S3 bucket.

Comment: A NoClassDefFoundError with the message "Could not initialize class XYZ" tells you that the JVM has already tried and failed to load this class and so refuses to load it again.  If you restart your app and go back through the logs, is there a different exception first time, probably an `ExceptionInInitializerError`? If so, that's the next thing to look at.